# Mercado Pago Error al obtener pagos

Tags: mercadopago

Este es un ejemplo que se puede encontrar en mercadopago.com
este me devuelve todos los pagos en lugar de regresear el que estoy buscando con el filtro. por que ?

```
$filters = array(
    "external_reference" => "EXTERNAL"
  );

  $payment = MercadoPago\Payment::search($filters);
```

Hay otros metodos de obtener los pagos como el siguiente en otra seccion de mercadopago.com

```
 require('mercadopago.php');
    $mp = new MP ("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");
    $payment = $mp->get(
        "/v1/payments/search",
        array(
            "external_reference" => "123456789"
        )
    );
```

El primer metodo para buscar pago solo requiere de CLIENT_ID y CLIENT_SECRET, pero el segundo metodo requiere el ACCESS TOKEN, por que ? cual es la diferencia ?
Se que con los 2 puedo obtener los pagos el problema es que el primer metodo no respeta los filtros.
Donde se ecuentra el archivo mercadopago.php? eh instalado el SDK y no viene ahi, entonces donde ?